# Error in accepting the value from console in c?

Tags: c

while working on the **c project** I found the following problem.
I declared a float variable and performed scanf operation on it. The sample code is -

```
<#include stdio.h>    
<#include conio.h>    
void main()    
{
   clrscr();
   float foo;
   scanf(" %f ",&foo);

   //remaining code goes here

   getch();
}
```

I found that the error is due to the spaces given after and before %f in **scanf** statement.
But I don't know what is the reason behind it ?
thanks.

Comment: `<#include stdio.h>` is a syntax error. `conio.h` is an ancient DOS thing, not standard C. `void main` is wrong. Don't randomly clear the screen in a command line program. To learn more about `scanf`, read its documentation.

Comment: Don't forget that `scanf()` tells you how many conversions it did successfully.  You need to check that you got one value converted, so: `if (scanf(" %f ", &foo) != 1) ... process error ...`.  The space before `%f` is harmless; numeric conversions skip leading white space (including newlines) anyway.  The trailing white space is problematic; `scanf()` is looking for a character other than white space after the number so it knows it has read enough.  I wish people were not taught `scanf()` at the beginning of a course in C; it is a fearsomely difficult function to use correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may help you a little.

the function `scanf` will read and ignore any whitespace characters encountered before the next non-whitespace character (whitespace characters include spaces, newline and tab characters -- see isspace).

```
A single whitespace in the format string validates any quantity of 
whitespace characters extracted from the stream (including none).
```

Also it should be like `#include<stdio.h>` not `<#include stdio.h>`

Comment: Hi Omkant. Syntax error for <#include stdio.h> was my mistake while posting the question. I got the your point about white space after %f. But I want to know what does the compiler actually do when it will come to know that there is a white space after %f ?